# From firebase storage download file to iframe

Tags: iframe, ember.js, firebase-storage

With below code, I can not download image to iframe. Instead, it downloaded to local drive.

in JS:

```
  storageRef.child('images/CopyPerson.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  var iframe1 = document.getElementById('downloadedCourse');
  iframe1.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

in html:

```
  <iframe id="downloadedCourse" width="800" height="500" src=""></iframe>
```

However, if I use img instead of iframe, it works as supposed.  The reason I need use iframe is because I intend to download pdf file. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that this is because the `content-disposition` header is set to `attachment` instead of `inline`. Try setting the metadata to change this and see if that works:

```
// Obviously you only have to set the metadata once per file
// Not every time you download the URL
storageRef.child('images/CopyPerson.jpg').updateMetadata({
  "contentDisposition": "inline"  
}).then(function() {
  return storageRef.child('images/CopyPerson.jpg').getDownloadURL()
}).then(function(url) {
  var iframe1 = document.getElementById('downloadedCourse');
  iframe1.src = url;
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I tried a couple of days without success.  First, setMetadata was not recognized, so I tried updateMetadata, but still the URL content only downloads instead of displaying in iframe. I figured this might be due to the URL itself. Since even if i directly copy that URL in browser, it still only downloads the file.  Still battling...

Comment: It has to do with how the browser interprets the `contentType` and `contentDisposition` so keep playing around with those.