# Can't Override Content-Disposition to 'inline' in Firebase Storage with Admin SDK for Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I want to override the default `content-disposition: attachment` HTTP header in Firebase Storage to `content-disposition: inline` for serving public images from my storage which are opened by browser (as `<a href="...">` links) for viewing (not downloaded).

Important default headers are the following:

```
content-disposition: attachment
content-type: image/jpeg
```

By default images are downloaded which I think is forced by `content-disposition: attachment`, that's why I try to override it during upload in Firebase Admin SDK:

```js
bucket.upload(photoUrl, {
  destination,
  public: true,
  metadata: {
    contentDisposition: 'inline',
  },
}).then((data) =>
  console.log(data[1].mediaLink),
);
```

I purge all the images in the storage and upload new with this code, but still I get `content-disposition: attachment`. Maybe it's by design, maybe my code is just wrong.

URLs to images look like: `https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/MY_PROJECT/o/IMAGE_PATH?generation=SOME_NUMBER&alt=media`.

What is the right way to override `content-disposition` to `inline` if it's possible?

Related question: [From firebase storage download file to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081018/from-firebase-storage-download-file-to-iframe)

#### Update

In Chrome devtools console I get warning: *"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg"*. I tried attaching `.jpg` extension to uploaded images destination, but I still get this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Official Answer

I've posted an issue into [nodejs-storage](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage) on GitHub and got [this response](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/321#issuecomment-410311987) from @stephenplusplus:

> I believe you'll need to use a signed URL for this behavior. The
>   mediaLink address appears to be meant for downloading, and also
>   requires authorization to access (unless you made your bucket/file
>   public).
>
> A signed URL will create a unique URL for users to access, unrelated
>   to the privacy of the Object in GCS. It will also inherit the metadata
>   you set. To get a signed URL that opens in the browser...

Modified code from his answer:

```js
bucket.upload(photoUrl, {
  destination,
}).then((data) => {

  const file = data[0];
  return file.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: '12-31-2118',
  });
}).then((data) =>
  console.log(data[0]),
);
```

See [signed URLs in Cloud Storage documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) and [`File.getSignedUrl` for NodeJS](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/File#getSignedUrl).

#### Workaround

```js
const blob = await fetch(mediaLink).then((res) => res.blob());
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// To keep adblockers away from your window:
const win = window.open();
win.document.head.innerHTML = `...<img src="${blobUrl}">...`;
```

Answer (score 3):

The metadata field is called [`Content-Disposition`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-disposition). Have you tried something like the following?

```
const meta = {};
meta['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline';
bucket.upload(photoUrl, {
  destination,
  public: true,
  metadata: meta,
});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work either. [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#request_properties_JSON) say I should use `contentDisposition`.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend filing an issue at https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage